# Name for function like Option.bind that returns Some(x) when input is None

Tags: f#, naming

The normal `Option.bind` function is defined like this:

```
// ('T -> 'U option) -> 'T option -> 'U option
let bind f x =
    match x with
    | None -> None
    | Some x' -> f x'
```

I am in need of a slightly different version of this:

```
// ('T -> 'U -> 'U option) -> 'T option -> ('U -> 'U option)
let myBind f x =
    match x with
    | None -> Some
    | Some x' -> f x'
```

**Does this function have a standard name?** (If not I'll gladly accept concise suggestions.)

---

For interested readers, my usecase is this: I have a business object (say `Order`) I want to apply a constraint to (order date, customer, etc.). The functions that apply constraints to e.g. an `Order` have signature `'Constraint -> Order -> Order option`. They return `Some order` if the order passed the constraint, and `None` otherwise (and can thus be composed using `Option.bind`). Now, if the constraint is `None`, it's essentially a no-op and `Some order` should be returned. Instead of having all constraint functions accept `'Constraint option` I can factor out this part of the logic using the function above (which then need to be applied during composition).

I originally called the function something like `bindConstraint`, but it's completely generic and really has nothing to do with my usecase (ref. Mark Seemann's [article on the topic](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/08/17/when-x-y-and-z-are-great-variable-names/)). Due to its similarity with `bind` I wondered if there is a standard name for this.

Comment: Your ``myBind`` function may compile but it returns a function, is that really what you are after? Also, how do you pass ``None`` into ``'Constraint``? Does that mean that your constraints are themselves options?

Comment: what would worry me is writing a bind that isn't really bind. Are you sure you can't refactor the "'U" out?

Comment: let me try to remember how to write f# and knock some code up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's look at your function type signature:

```
// ('T -> 'U -> 'U option) -> 'T option -> ('U -> 'U option)
```

The `'U -> 'U option` type can actually be factored out of that signature. Let's call that type `'V`. Then the type signature becomes:

```
// ('T -> 'V) -> 'T option -> 'V
```

Which looks rather similar to `Option.map`, whose signature is:

```
// ('T -> 'V) -> 'T option -> 'V option
```

So basically, your function is equivalent to `Option.map` followed by a `defaultArg` to turn that `'V option` into a `'V` (supplying a default value if the option was `None`).

So I'd probably call it something like `defaultMap` or `mapDefault`.

Comment: Thanks, your breakdown makes sense and `defaultMap`/`mapDefault` seems like good names.

Answer (score 1):

hmmm...

I was wondering if you factor out the 'U, that you end up working inside a reader monad, and then your function IS option.bind there's nothing to do!

'U -> .....('T -> 'U option) -> 'T option -> 'U option

i.e. this is a constraint on string?

```
let longerThan : int -> string -> string option =
fun i s -> 
    if (String.length s > i) then 
        Some s
    else
        None
```

and this is you using myBind

```
let foo = myBind longerThan (Some 1)
```

but this is the code without myBind

```
let bar = 
fun s -> 
    (Some 1) |> Option.bind (fun i -> longerThan i s)
```

we've just factored out the 'U and we write our code inside a function.

(my code looks more complex because we've written longer than to work nicely with your bind, if we swap the parameter order, then your version looks more complex than mine)

my other observation is if you are just doing constraints, then isn't using

'U -> bool

a bit simpler?...and then you just use "where"...(can you do this in a computational expression?...you can in LINQ I think).

P.S.

actually the semantics of your code Is different...you want None to be interpreted as the identity map....

Comment: Regarding `bool` and `where`: I want to compose several constraint functions together in an "AND" manner, and using option-returning functions with `Option.bind` seemed a good choice. It seems to me that using `bool`-returning functions would require more plumbing in order to compose them together?

Comment: Oh wait, you can just ``&&`` them (at least by passing the `Order` argument to each of them; I don't know if there is a more succinct way of just composing them without passing the final argument). This whole thing seems to be a case of thinking too complicated. I'll let it simmer for a while and see what I come up with.

Comment: let it simmer...I haven't answered your question really, but what you want to do seems so close to "standard" constructs that I makes me think that if you tweak it a bit, you will have something that feels much more natural....Boolean algebra and "where" is very natural.....the previous answer I did with composing constraints...is more natural (to me) than your construct.....but it may not fit your use case

Answer (score 1):

so actually I think in your world I would operate on the constraint directly

```
type Constraint<'a> = 'a -> 'a option

let applyConstraint : Constraint<'a> option -> 'a -> 'a option =
function 
|   None    ->  Some
|   Some f  ->  f
```

and then simply compose constraints;

```
let compose : Constraint<'a> -> Constraint<'a> -> Constraint<'a> =
fun c1 c2 -> fun a -> Option.bind c2 (c1 a)
```

(though I may have c1 and c2 the wrong way around)